# Produce a dataframe from comparison process

Tags: r

As input dataframe having a data structure like this:

```
dframe <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), col1 = c(4.2, 1.2), su = c(1.2,2.4))
```

How is it possible to compare the number in every row for the two columns and according to the greatest produce a new column which will have the col name of the greatest value and a second column with this value?

```
dcom <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), col1 = c(4.2, 1.2), su = c(1.2,2.4), com = c("col1", "su"), com_num = c(4.2, 2.4))
dcom
  id col1  su  com com_num
1  1  4.2 1.2 col1     4.2
2  2  1.2 2.4   su     2.4
```

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, apply(dframe[-1], 1, function(x) {i1 <- which.max(x); data.frame(names(x)[i1], x[i1])}))`

Comment: `with(dframe, pmax(col1, su))` gives the maxima but not the column names.

Comment: To get the column name `cbind(dframe, com = names(dframe)[-1][max.col(dframe[-1])], com_num = do.call(pmax, dframe[-1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized solution can be the following.

```
com_num <- with(dframe, pmax(col1, su))
i <- which(dframe[-1] == com_num, arr.ind = TRUE)
dframe$com <- names(dframe[-1])[i[, 2]]
dframe$com_num <- com_num

dframe
#  id col1  su  com com_num
#1  1  4.2 1.2 col1     4.2
#2  2  1.2 2.4   su     2.4
```

Comment: One more question if we have zero in both case `dframe <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), col1 = c(4.2, 1.2,0), su = c(1.2,2.4,0))` for com column if the case is 0-0 can we insert a text like "zerohere"?